# How to add an id to the path of an svg in a webpage?

Tags: javascript, svg

Here is my webpage:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Bin Labeler</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <embed class="emb" src="racks.svg" style="position: relative;
            width:100%;
            height:100%"/>
            <script>//<![CDATA[
// wait until all the resources are loaded
window.addEventListener("load", findSVGElements, false);

// fetches the document for the given embedding_element
function getSubDocument(embedding_element)
{
    if (embedding_element.contentDocument) 
    {
        return embedding_element.contentDocument;
    } 
    else 
    {
        var subdoc = null;
        try {
            subdoc = embedding_element.getSVGDocument();
        } catch(e) {}
        return subdoc;
    }
}
function findSVGElements()
{
    var elm = document.querySelector('.emb');
    var subdoc = getSubDocument(elm);
    if (subdoc)
            var paths = subdoc.querySelectorAll("path");
                paths.forEach(function(path){
                  path.addEventListener('click',function(e){
                var bin_id = prompt("What ID belongs to this rack?","Enter here...");
                e.target.id=bin_id;
                path.setAttribute('fill','green');
                console.log(e.target);
                    })
                });
}

//]]>

            </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

As you can see, its loading the svg xml into my findSVGElements function and then adding an event listener where for each one, an alert shows up asking for the id. Then I am setting e.target.id hopefully to add the id element to the svg. Then when I do "View Frame source" which gives the svg and all of its paths, I am hoping that the bin_id that the user types in to the alert box becomes the id attribute for that path element. However, it does not seem to do this when I View Frame source, I am simply viewing the original svg that was loaded to the page.

How can I do this?

Comment: what happens when you change `e.target.id` to `path.id`?

Comment: it still doesn't have the updated id in the svg source - thought                 console.log(e.target); does print the path with the id

Comment: is it possible for you to create a jsfiddle of it?

Comment: Please create a [mcve].

Comment: I created this: https://jsfiddle.net/27rmuoeo/6/ which has the code, but you will see in the console, it doesn't want to get an SVGdocument for an external source (cross-origin frame execution error). Im not sure how to host the svg on jsfiddle. However, if you can run it locally, the svg is hosted here: https://svgshare.com/i/5w9.svg